# get JSON file from remote Server

Tags: jsp

When I try to get json file from the server,using jquery method like this:

```js
$.ajax({
                url: 'sample/0301_01.json',
                type: 'get',
                dataType:'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("sdf");
                }
            });
```

And I using firefox browser to test the result. It turns out no error,but the server response message like that:An error occurred during the processing of /sample/0301_01.json.
The page must have a <%@ webservice class="MyNamespace.MyClass" ... %> directive
Can you help me?

Comment: seems as though the json file is the problem. have you tried it with any other file?

Answer (score 1):

That's an exception thrown by the asp.net server which hosts the json file. You need to fix that error for getting the JSON file.

I think a namespace is missing from the .cs file in the asp.net server. Login to the ftp of that server and add the namespace.

```
        using <namespacename>;
```

[Read this msdn documentation about using c# namspaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfb3cx8s.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I want to know whether I can just read a static json file in the remote server. And in my project, We are also using requirejs and knockoutJS, I just want to know whether those technoly can support visiting static text file in the remote server?

Comment: @AllenJoe Yeah for sure :)  Javascript xhr request's doesn't check whether the json is generated by your server or not. You can use static json's or server generated ones. thanks man :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I try to change the json file suffix to *.txt. It work! But I don't know why the server can't receive *.json file request.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your server doesn't know how to respond to `sample/0301_01.json`
Have you tried visiting that page directly (without ajax - in a browser)?

Comment: right, so the issue is the server not your jQuery request.